# Round double to 6th decimal place in C#

Tags: c#, double, rounding

**Note**: I'd like to state that I have made reasonable effort to find a solution on my own and on other asked questions, before submitting my question - however the solutions I found did not fit my needs.

An API I'm using returns a **double** with 7 decimal places, e.g. : 1495120024.7705889

However I need to print this (or return a string) as: **1495120024.770589** - basically rounded to six decimal places.

What originally seemed like a trivial thing to do is turning out to be mind-wrecking.

These are the approaches I have tried (assume above value is stored in a double called *d*):

`d.ToString()` = 1495120024.77059

`d.ToString("F6")` = 1495120024.770590

`d.ToString("F7")` = 1495120024.7705900

`Math.Round(d, 6)` = 1495120024.7705891 - [rounding error?]

`Math.Truncate(d * 1000000) / 1000000` = 1495120024.7705879

`Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Truncate(d * 1000000))` = 1495120024770590

`Convert.ToDecimal(d)` = 1495120024.77059

I know this sounds silly, but I need it to be rounded to exactly six decimal places and properly set to string. I am also aware of rounding errors in doubles, but sadly I have no control over the datatype returned by the API.

**Edit v1:**

Based on a comment by [BWA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5481787), this is the solution I have come up with:

`var s = Math.Round(d - Math.Truncate(d), 6).ToString();
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(".") + 1);
s = $"{Math.Truncate(d)}.{s}";`

But the word *hack* doesn't even begin to describe this...

Comment: The one marked [rounding error] is legitimate, the exact value is 1495120024.7705891132354736328125 (which is the closest you can come to 1495120024.770589, and thus also the actual result of typing in `double x = 1495120024.770589;`). It's a bit annoying that it gets printed that way, I suppose (it is not the shortest string that parses back to the value). I'm not sure what's wrong with the F6 formatting though

Comment: I would have been fine with that little bit of rounding error as long as I find a suitable way of converting it to string and then possibly trimming that off. But even the act of converting to a string messes it up :(

Comment: It is *floating* point, the position of the decimal point is not relevant.  `float` can store 6 significant digits, `double` can store 15 digits.  You'll lose digits if the calculation is convoluted.  You only see 17 digits because that is what the debugger uses to convert the *binary* value to decimal.  Rounding to 16 digits just misleads anybody in assuming the result is more accurate than it can possibly be.  It doesn't fool the machine, the last digit is just random noise.  The only way to get ahead to meet your demand is to do all of your math in `decimal`, it can store 28 digits.

Comment: Any code snippets @HansPassant ? As I said, the datatype I receive is double and I cannot change that. Trying to cast to decimal also ruins the number prior to any other calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 256.7705889;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F6"));
```

Writes

> 256.770589

But

```
double d = 1121111156.7705889;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F6"));
```

Writes:

```
1121111156.770590
```

Problem is how double works. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

Shortly: longer part before . = less precision.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question since you're using a different value... But it does give me an idea (aka. _hack_) ... Reducing the number of significant places just to get the correct decimal places, then string append to the original truncated number...

Comment: @ZuiqPazu What number you have in raw message from API? Mayby you neet to capture raw message and manual parse response to decimal.

Comment: The number varies, but the one in question is: 1495120024.7705889 as double.

Comment: So maybe just capute respone from api and manual parse it. If you have string 1495120024.7705889 you can parse it to decimal.

Comment: As I have said, I receive a double from the API. There is no conversion from string from my end.

Comment: Based on your answer though I have made an edit on my original question to add a hacky solution.

Comment: @ZuiqPazu framework converts string from response to your objects. If you catch response message before framework you can fill objects in your way. So you can convert string representation of your problematic double to decimal.